# How do I solve this error: TypeError: search() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'

Tags: python

The `check_web_address` function checks if the text passed qualifies as a top-level web address, meaning that it contains alphanumeric characters (which includes letters, numbers, and underscores), as well as periods, dashes, and a plus sign, followed by a period and a character-only top-level domain such as ".com", ".info", ".edu", etc. Fill in the regular expression to do that, using escape characters, wildcards, repetition qualifiers, beginning and end-of-line characters, and character classes.

```
import re

def check_web_address(text):
    pattern = re.search(r'^[*\.]+[\w\-\.]+[\w\w\w]*$')
    result = re.search(pattern, text)
    return result != None
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When you first wrote `re.search`, you should just not call `re.search` and instead assign the string to the variable.

Comment: It looks like you meant to call `re.compile` instead of `re.search`. Alternatively, you could leave out the call entirely since compilation doesn't get you any net benefit here AFAIK. Or maybe you meant to put everything in one line, like `result = re.search(r'...', text)`. Anyway, I'm voting to close the question since the problem is a typo or other trivial mistake. In the future, please make a [mre], which will help catch things like this. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! For more tips, see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You sound like you are doing homework! Well, the regex is good.

Anyways, the problem happens in the `pattern =` bit. You should've been able to see that if you checked the line number. [`re.search` takes two strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search), but you only gave it one.

You are not searching for anything yet, so you should not call `re.search` at all there. This would give:

```py
def check_web_address(text):
   pattern = r'^[*\.]+[\w\-\.]+[\w\w\w]*$'
   result = re.search(pattern, text)
   return result != None
```

There is one case where people call an `re` function on the expression before searching: you may want to compile the expression into an *regular expression object*, so that future searches do not need to parse the expression again. This would look like:

```py
WEB_ADDRESS_PATTERN = re.compile(r'^[*\.]+[\w\-\.]+[\w\w\w]*$')
def check_web_address(text):
   result = WEB_ADDRESS_PATTERN.search(text)
   return result != None
```

Maybe that pattern is what got you confused?

At the risk of getting ahead of yourself, here we call [the `search` method of the `WEB_ADDRESS_PATTERN` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search), which only takes one string argument: the haystack to search in.